# Eclipse RCP setselectionprovider not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using the following code to set the selection provider outside the createpartcontrol method of the view, my project view is restricted wherein the createpartcontrol is a generic and I will not be able to use the selection provider inside it. The following code does not work with enabling menu by property testers where in I am using `<enabled when> variable="selection" </enabled when>` when the view loads initially but when click outside the view and click backed into the view then property testers works fine and my menu items get enabled.

Also I found this post in the eclipse documentation that Replacing the selection provider during the lifetime of the part is not properly supported by the workbench :

https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html

Not sure where am i going wrong? Could someone provide some help with respect to this.
Also when i debug through eclipse it goes through this part of the code and everything works fine , but when run as an application outside debug mode the issue occurs.

```
IWorkbenchWindow iw = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
iw.getActivePage().getActivePart().getSite().setSelectionProvider(objectComposite.getViewer());
```

Comment: If you are not doing this in createPartControl where are you doing it?

Comment: In the createPartControl method only the parentcomposite is being created and depending on scenarios it bifurcates to the appropriate class wherein the child items to the parentcomposite are being created. In these classes i want to use the setselectionprovider but it does not work properly and also the eclipse documentation states the same . I am just looking out for alternate options for implementing it.